# Python: new data frame from group_by with new index in one line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am new to Python and would like to get more efficient in coding.

Currently I have the following code, counting the number of shops per city, if the shop is still open:

```
top_20_cities = pd.DataFrame(data = shops[shops.Open == 'Open'].groupby('city').size().sort_values(ascending=False).head(20)).reset_index()
top_20_cities.columns = ['City', 'Count']
```

Is it possible, put both lines into one? I tried this, but get an error:

```
top_20_cities = pd.DataFrame(data = shops[shops.Open == 'Open'].groupby('city').size().sort_values(ascending=False).head(20), columns = ['City', 'Count']).reset_index()
```

thx

Comment: If you are happy having `city` without capital C you can just do `.reset_index(name='Count')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
top_20_cities = (shops[shops.Open == 'Open']
                   .groupby('city')
                   .size()
                   .sort_values(ascending=False)
                   .head(20)
                   .rename_axis('City')
                   .reset_index(name='Count'))
```

Another solution with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) which sorting by default:

```
top_20_cities = (shops.loc[shops.Open == 'Open', 'city']
                      .value_counts()
                      .head(20)
                      .rename_axis('City')
                      .reset_index(name='Count'))
```